# Where are custom kernels being flashed to in internal memory?

Tags: rom-flashing, kernel

I've unzipped zip files for custom kernels and noticed that the majority of the files that are being applied are in a /kernel folder. However that folder is unlisted when listing the root directories using both Root Explorer and ES File Explorer. Where is this /kernel folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel is part of the "boot image", which is stored in a separate partition in the flash memory, not in a normal file. See http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Unpack,_Edit,_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images

Answer (score 0):

May be you can explain a little bit more on what you are trying to do..
Also, if you can list those custom kernel files, we can help better.

If I need to flash a custom kernel, I follow below process:

1. Get the source from the git repository
2. Make my changes to the kernel source. Change could vary from adding a simple debug printk statement to adding a new driver.
3. Build the kernel source using cross-compiler toolchain
4. Change the phone to Fastboot mode (I'm talking bout G1 phone)
5. Use 'fastboot' to flash the custom kernel (zImage) using command: 'fastboot flash:raw boot zImage ramdisk.img'
6. Use 'fastboot reboot' command to reboot the phone using the new kernel

Hope there is some clarity now.